# Agrupar tabelas e retornar em json

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Tenho esta função que retorna os dados para o Ajax:

```
public function get_agenda(){
    $this->db->select('prospect_agendamento.age_data_agendado_para as start, prospect.pro_nome as title, prospect.pro_id as id ');
    $this->db->where('prospect_agendamento.age_data_agendado_para BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['start'])). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['end'])).'"');
    $this->db->join("prospect", "prospect.pro_id=prospect_agendamento.age_id_prospect");
    $retorno = $this->db->get('prospect_agendamento')->result();
    echo json_encode($retorno); 
}
```

Até então, tudo funciona perfeitamente.
Porém, eu preciso adicionar a este mesmo retorno, uma outra listagem, que irá compor o json.

Que seria dessa estrutura de tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A outra função que eu tenho para agrupar é esta:

```
public function get_agenda_1(){
    $this->db->select('tarefa.tar_data_inicial as start, tarefa.tar_data_final as end, tarefa.tar_titulo as title');
    $retorno = $this->db->get('tarefa')->result();
    echo json_encode($retorno);
}
```

Como eu posso fazer uma nova lista?

Comment: Os retornos são diferentes ? de cada função eu digo ...

Comment: Sao os mesmos, title, start e end

Comment: Estão diferentes pelo que vi da uma olhada

Comment: Sim, os campos das tabelas são diferentes, mas o retorno que eu preciso são iguais.